# How to create Bean class in Javascript like Java?

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, oop, javascript-framework

I may sound weird for this, please forgive me if this is an off topic question, but Since I came from java background and now working on nodejs last 1 week, at many places I personally felt that I should use something like **Bean** architecture with **setters and getters** feature (as we do have in java term).

Is there any way through which I can achieve this in nodejs/javascript ?,

suppose I have json data in my hand retrieved from db call, how can I convert it into a class with respective properties ?

(I have intermediate knowledge about javascript and prototype.)
Any help would be appreciated... thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON that you get is already an object =) 
Any way you can create a constructor function and pass this json as parameter. And do whatever you like

Comment: I agree with you that JSON is already an object... scenario may be like not to display every data in json at client side.

Comment: JSON is a *string*. You *parse* it into an object.

Answer (score 0):

In addition of topic Getter/Setter  look at

```
 __defineGetter__
 __defineSetter__
```

they are default basic object methods, to specify getters and setters in JS (not sure abount NODE)

Comment: Moraz this was nice, appreciated. but when I look at MDN doc, it says its outdated and deprecated. link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter